# Validation at both Service and Controller Layer?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Is there a need to do another round of input validation, non business logic related in the `service` layer?

**Service Layer**

```
@Service
@Transactional
@Validated
public class AppServiceImpl implements AppService {

    public App createApp(@Valid App app) { // is there a need to do @Valid here?
        return appRepository.save(app);
    }
}
```

**Controller Layer**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class AppResource {
    private final AppRepository appRepository;

    private final AppServiceImpl appServiceImpl;

    @Autowired
    public AppResource(AppRepository appRepository, AppServiceImpl appServiceImpl) {
        this.appServiceImpl = appServiceImpl;
        this.appRepository = appRepository;
    }

    /**
     * POST  /apps : Create a new app.
     *
     * @param app the app to create
     * @return the ResponseEntity with status 201 (Created) and with body the new app, or with status 400 (Bad Request) if the app has already an ID
     * @throws URISyntaxException if the Location URI syntax is incorrect
     */
    @PostMapping("/apps")
    @Timed
    public ResponseEntity<App> createApp(@Valid @RequestBody App app) throws URISyntaxException {
        log.debug("REST request to save App : {}", app);
        if (app.getId() != null) {
            return ResponseEntity.badRequest().headers(HeaderUtil.createFailureAlert(ENTITY_NAME, "idexists", "A new app cannot already have an ID")).body(null);
        }
        App result = appServiceImpl.createApp(app);
        return ResponseEntity.created(new URI("/api/apps/" + result.getId()))
            .headers(HeaderUtil.createEntityCreationAlert(ENTITY_NAME, result.getId().toString()))
            .body(result);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Short form: Yes, you have to validate again.

From design perspective your class provides an public interface where you in general don't know who invokes the method. So for your class / method to ensure to work properly you'll have to validate the input.

If the context the class is used in is well known and you "know" that the validation is done before you may skip the additional validation. In this case you are accepting the risk that if in the future the validation is not done in the Controlling Layer or you add additional classes / use cases the invocation may fail or give unexpected results.

Comment: Make sense. What is the general approach for the `Service` layer to relay up the validation error up to the `Controller` layer then?

Comment: In the `Controller` layer we can make use of @ControllerAdvice to handle any exception and directly return a JSON in ResponseBody.

Comment: If you want to keep the effort small just propagate the validation error / exception to the `Controller`. As you've already mentioned you can use `@ControllerAdvice` for handling the exception.

Comment: andih -> thx for very good perspective with introducing the idea of "Controlling layer" which we decide to trust or not. It gives excellent perspective on the matter which a lot of StackOverflow answers on the same topic are missing...

@Gavin I now it's very old thread but another very valid approach is to use parametrized results Result<T> which return result or error so you are not forced to throw and catch exceptions ...